# ¿Cómo modifico una variable global desde una función?

Tags: python

Tengo un problema y es que no tengo la menor idea de cómo puedo modificar una variable global a partir de una función se me había ocurrido algo pero no me funcionó ¿Cómo podría hacerle?

```
agape = 0
eros = 0
pragma = 0
mania = 0
ludus = 0



def ask(type, ask):

    print(ask)
    points = input("Elige una respuesta: ")
    points = float(points)
    return type + points


ask(agape, "¿funcionará?")
print(agape)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para modificar variables globales tienes que declararlas con la palabra reservada **`global`** dentro de tu función y listo, no es necesario que hagas un `return` en la función.

```
agape = 0
eros = 0
pragma = 0
mania = 0
ludus = 0

def ask(ask):

    global agape

    print(ask)
    points = float(input("Elige una respuesta: "))
    agape = agape + points
    return agape

ask("¿funcionará?")

print(agape)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! :)

Comment: @DiegoNavarro marca la respuesta como correcta para que de esa forma puedas ayudar a la comunidad a identificar de forma mas rapida la resolucion a este problema.